# Responsive divs 50% height of viewport size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

I try to make a grid of four boxes each 50% height and 50% width of the full screen size, like shown in this picture:
http://a.pomf.se/gqnzzs.jpg

My problem is that I can't get the 50% height to work. How can I set the height of 2 div above each other at each a height of 50% of the viewport size?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel-1">... </div>
    <div class="panel-2">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel-3">...</div>
    <div class="panel-4">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;}

.panel-1{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;}

.panel-2{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;}

.panel-3{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;}

.panel-4{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 50%;}
```

I greatly appreciate any help!

Greets

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [supported browsers,](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) you can use [viewport-percentages units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, `vmax`.

In this case, just use `50vh`, where 1 unit equals 1% of the height of the initial containing block.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ede7mde/)

```
.panel-1, .panel-2,
.panel-3, .panel-4 {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

For what it's worth, if you want to still use percentage based units, you would need to define all the parent element's heights too:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2g2fjavn/)

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.row {
    height: 50%;
}
.panel-1, .panel-2,
.panel-3, .panel-4 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! And seems to work in all major browsers, including IE9. I'd say that's good enough! Especially where Windows 10 won't use IE anymore. Thanks a lot for the fast reply!

Answer (score 3):

Solved by **flexbox**. [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

No float, no clearfixes - simple and clear;

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #333;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -o-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -o-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -o-box-lines: multiple;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex__item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -o-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #777;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.flex__item:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #9aa0a8;
}
.flex__item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #a7c4b5;
}
.flex__item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #a9d8b8;
}
.flex__item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #beffc7;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__item"></div>
<div class="flex__item"></div>
<div class="flex__item"></div>
<div class="flex__item"></div>
```

Comment: Vanilla! Gives even more browser support. Thanks a lot! Now I just need to integrate it with foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following:
html {  height:100%;    width:100%;}
body { width:100%;height:100%;}

Then "div" will work with "height:50%".